# Java soap client to wsdl url

Tags: java, soap

i want to call soap function with a few parameters. I did it python but how can i do it on java ?

my code on python :

```
        url = 'http://78.188.50.246:8086/iskultur?singleWsdl'
        client = Client(url)

        d = dict(UserId='a', UserPass='b', Barkod=str(value))

        result = client.service.Stok(**d)
        return int(result)
```

how can i do it on java ?

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to generate proxy classes. You can do that using `wsimport` (it's a Java SE tool):

```
wsimport -keep http://78.188.50.246:8086/iskultur?singleWsdl
```

This will generate classes (in packages) and place the results in the current directory. I tested your URL and it generated two package hierarchies (one starting in 'org' and the other in 'com'). The command above will keep the source code, so you can move those directories to your Java project source path (later you should include this code generation step in your build process).

with the generated classes in your classpath, you now create a `Service` instance from your `WSDL` (passing the URL and the namespace qualified name of your service). I got that information from the WSDL.

```
URL wsdlLocation = new URL("http://78.188.50.246:8086/iskultur?singleWsdl");
QName serviceName = new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "EbWCFtoLogo");

Service service = Service.create(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
```

Then you get a proxy where you can call your SOAP methods with `Service.getPort()` passing the interface of the port (`IEbWCFtoLogo`). Now you have a reference where you can call your remote SOAP methods.

```
IEbWCFtoLogo proxy = service.getPort(IEbWCFtoLogo.class);
```

The `wsimport` tool generated a `stok()` method that receives 3 parameters. I called with some of the values you used and it returned `-1.0` in the code below:

```
double value = proxy.stok("a", "b", "code");
System.out.println("Result: " + value);
```

Comment: Hi so thanks for your detailed description. I did wsimport it generate two folder as u said. how can include they my project on netbeans ?

Comment: So so so thanks , finally i manage it thank to u :) So much thanks